# Inheriting old methods in version 8

Tags: odoo

When I'm writing a custom module which overrides current methods, does that need to be written in the same version of the api?

For example module product is written in v7, when I'm overriding methods of product, does that need to be in v7 or can I do this in v8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update just code odoo engine it self manages upgrade/downgrade mechanism according to need.

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class product_product(models.Model):
    _inherit= "product.product"
    _description = "Product"

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        ### Add your code here
        return super(product_product, self).create(vals);

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        ### Add your code here
        return super(product_product, self).write(vals);
```

Similarly you can override any methods of the old version except onchange methods. in onchange methods you need to provide definition in old pattern.

Answer (score 2):

yes definitely you can override in v7 method to v8

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class product_product(models.Model):
    _inherit= "product.product"
    _description = "Product"

@api.v7
def _product_code(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    for p in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[p.id] = self._get_partner_code_name(cr, uid, [], p, context.get('partner_id', None), context=context)['code']
    return res
```

I am just override the v7 `_product_code method` in my new API product class for Odoo 8.0.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: The only case where you can't do this is for `onchange`, where you can't mix new API and old API.

Comment: It means my method does not work for on change call right ..??